# Mysql update query with inner table join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem with update query in mysql. 
When I try this

```
update planned_expense p1 
set deleted=1 
where case_id=204 
  and deleted =0  
  and type='MONTHLY' 
  and planned_date>='2017-04-01'  
  and id > (select min(id) from planned_expense p2 where 
             p2.case_id = p1.case_id 
               and  p2.planned_date = p1.planned_date 
               and  p2.account = p1.account 
               and p2.type = p1.type and p2.deleted = 0)
```

I get

**You can't specify target table 'p1' for update in FROM clause**

And when I try

```
update planned_expense p1  
set deleted=1 
where case_id=204 
and deleted =0   
and type='MONTHLY'  
and planned_date>='2017-04-01'   
and id > (select min(id)  
    from (select * from planned_expense p2  
    where p2.case_id=p1.case_id and   
    p2.planned_date=p1.planned_date  
    and p2.account=p1.account and p2.type=p1.type and p2.deleted=0) p3)
```

I get

**Unknown column 'p1.case_id' in 'where clause'**

What should I write in order to update those records?
Tnank you.

This is my table

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bes-ers`.`planned_expense`;
CREATE TABLE  `bes-ers`.`planned_expense` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `case_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `planned_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `addition_mark` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `planned_amount` decimal(22,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `account` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `search_field` varchar(4096) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(4096) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_by_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locked` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `FK_planned_expenses_1` (`case_id`),
  KEY `FK_planned_expenses_created_by_id` (`created_by_id`),
  KEY `planned_expense_planned_date` (`planned_date`),
  KEY `planned_expense_type` (`type`),
  KEY `planned_expense_deleted` (`deleted`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_planned_expenses_1` FOREIGN KEY (`case_id`) REFERENCES `bankruptcy_case` (`ID`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE SET NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_planned_expenses_created_by_id` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=13172954 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: First step to debug: write readable code. If you have trouble, use a formatter: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: Thanks Jacob for advice.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql don't allow the update  of the table if is involved  in select but you can avoid this problem using a dinamica select table eg:

```
    update planned_expense 
      set deleted=1 
      where case_id=204 
      and deleted =0  
      and type='MONTHLY' 
      and planned_date>='2017-04-01'  
      and id > ( select t.min_id from (select min(id)  min_id 
                from planned_expense p2 
                INNER JOIN planned_expense p1 on p2.case_id=p1.case_id 
                        and  p2.planned_date=p1.planned_date 
                    and p2.account=p1.account 
                    and p2.type=p1.type and p2.deleted=0) t )
```

try adding a composite index as

```
create index idx_test on planned_expense (case_id, planned_date, account)
```

Comment: thanks scaisEdge but I still get Unknown column 'p1.case_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: Thanks again scairsEdge but this query is too slow. I left it over the weekend but it hasn't finished yet.

Comment: have you proper compiste index on  table planned_expense , column (case_id, deleted, type, planned_date, id) ???

Comment: There is no composite index on this table.

Comment: update your question and add  the schema for the involved  tables

Comment: I'm sorry for bad formatting I tried using tool Jacob told me to, but I'm not good at using it

Comment: i have update my answer  with a suggestion for composite index

Answer (score 0):

As explained by @scaisEdge, you have to use a join and to speed up you query,
try creating a composite key as per your where clause.
Something like:
KEY case_id_deleted_type_planned_date_id (case_id, deleted, type, planned_date, id)
Use Explain to check if your query is using proper indexes or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I did what I wanted to by creating temp table and than working with it.

Thanks for